# Javascript function not defined if from a separate file?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

Here is my code:
I am calling the function run() on the click of a button. run() will call the function main() from the source code of bundle.js. The console logs that the function main() is not defined. I even tried running it in the console itself with no success.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function run() {
    main(document.getElementById('playlistUrl').value)
  }
</script>


<input id="playlistUrl" placeholder="Enter a link...">
<button onclick="run()" id="go">Go!</button>
```

the function run() is defined, but not any funtion from bundle.js

Comment: Can you check whether bundle.js is loaded at the time when you are invoking main(). If not loaded , you can use document.readyState to wait till the script is being loaded https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyStat

Comment: is bundle.js a custom script you have or something from an external library you added?

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine!, check your file location or fails in bundle.js file

```js
//bundle.js file

function main(value){
    console.log(value);
}
```

```js
//main.js file

function run() {
    main(document.getElementById('playlistUrl').value)
  }
```

```html
<input id="playlistUrl" placeholder="Enter a link...">
<button onclick="run()" id="go">Go!</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  

<script type="text/javascript">
  function run() {
    main(document.getElementById('playlistUrl').value)
  }
</script>


<input id="playlistUrl" placeholder="Enter a link...">
<button onclick="run()" id="go">Go!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for bundle.js:

```
function main(){
    document.write("Main ran")
}
```